# Automated testing of APIs with notifications

Tags: api, software-testing, notification

I've been searching for a software that would test APIs and after testing them it would send notifications to our server if anything isn't working properly. I'm currently using Insomnia and even though I can test anything I want there, I have to do it manually. Is there actually any app that does this service fully automated?

Appreciate the help, if any further questions don't hesitate!

Comment: Start by looking at Selenium

Answer (score 0):

In [SOAPUI](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html), you can run Groovy scripts as part of your Test Steps and with that do numerous things that might suit... e.g. [sending an email](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Send-automatic-email/td-p/123022)/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! I had already tried soapui, even though I thought it was good, they don't want to manually type scripts. So I was trying to find something that did all of that fully automated, like postman where you can receive e-mails but server wise. I'll point this one though in case I don't find a software that does what they want! Once again, thanks for the answer.